# Read from a text file, sort it, and write it again

Tags: java, arrays

So our professor has assigned us with a program which reads a text file he has provided us with; it sorts it, and creates a new file with the sorted stuff. He wants us to call three methods from the main i.e. read, sort, and write

I have done some of the work, but i'm confused what arguments to provide for io.sort. And how do i convert that text thing into an array to provide an argument  Here's my code:

```
public void read() {
    try {
        Scanner myLocal = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));
        while (myLocal.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(myLocal.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void sort(String[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            /* ERROR: When j == 0, j - 1 == -1, which is out of bounds */
            if (arr[j - 1].compareTo(arr[j]) > 0) { 
                swap(j, arr);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void swap(int j, String[] arr) {
    String temp = arr[j - 1];
    arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

public void write() {
    try {
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(new File("sorted.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            writer.println(i);
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: first step - instead of printing out the contents of the input file, store it in an array

Comment: i've posted the new read method below, as you told me.

Comment: somehow I have a feeling that your professor wants you to solve this assignement instead of the stackoverflow community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CORRECT CODE (SOLVED)**

class IO{

```
String[] myArray = new String[30000];

public void read()
{

    try {
        Scanner myLocal = new Scanner( new File("dictionary.txt"));  
        while (myLocal.hasNextLine()){

                for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
                String a = myLocal.nextLine();
                myArray[i] = a;

            }
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void sort()
{   
    int n = myArray.length;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<n-i; j++){ 
        if (myArray[j-1].compareTo(myArray[j])>0){



                swap(j, myArray);



            }

        }


    } 



}
public void swap(int j, String[] myArray)
{
    String temp = myArray[j-1];
    myArray[j-1]=myArray[j];
    myArray[j]=temp;


}

public void write()
{
    try{
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(new File("myIgnoreNew.txt"));
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
            writer.println(myArray[i] + "\n");
            }
            writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Try to get used to using try-with-resources for these kinds of read and write. Look it up, it's very straightforward to use and a good habit to have.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i've changed my read() method:

```
public void read()
{
    String[] myArray = new String[1000];
    try {
        Scanner myLocal = new Scanner( new File("dictionary.txt"));  
        String a = myLocal.nextLine();
        while (myLocal.hasNextLine()){
            for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
                myArray[i] = a;
            }                   

        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, the problem with this is that the scope of `myArray` is limited to the `read` method.  Either add a return type of `String[]` or move the declaration of  `myArray` to a field

Comment: Also you want `String a = myLocal.nextLine();` to be in the `while` loop so that its value changes each time

Comment: You should change you initial question instead of creating a 'non' answer

Answer (score 1):

```
class IO{
String[] myArray = new String[30000];

public void read()
{

    try {
        Scanner myLocal = new Scanner( new File("dictionary.txt"));  
        while (myLocal.hasNextLine()){

                for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
                String a = myLocal.nextLine();
                myArray[i] = a;

            }
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void sort()
{   
    int n = myArray.length;
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n-i-1; j++){
            if(myArray[j+1].compareTo(myArray[j])<0){
                String temp = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = myArray[j+1];
                myArray[j+1] = temp;
                //toLower
            }
        }

    }



}

public void swap(int j, String[] arr)
{

    String temp = arr[j-1];
    arr[j-1] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

public void write()
{

    try{
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(new File("sorted.txt"));
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
            writer.println(myArray[i] + "\n");
            }
            writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}
```

}